# int captured by value or by reference

Tags: c#

Can someone explain the behaviuor of this program:

```
using System;
namespace lambda
{

    internal class Program
    {

        static Action a;
        static void fun1()
        {
            // this is local
            int x = 3;

            // lambda a : x captured by value or by reference?
            a = () => { ++x ; };

            // call lambda
            a();

            // x now equals 4
            int b = x;

        }

        static void fun2()
        {
            // call lambda: inside lambda x equals 5
            a();

        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            fun1();
            fun2 ();
        }
    }
}
```

In particular I don't understand if x of the lambda is a reference to local x, how can i call a inside fun2?

Comment: I would avoid writing code like this since it can really hamper readability. Your example would be easier to read and understand if it took `x` as an parameter and returned the incremented result, and called something descriptive, like `Increment`.

Comment: @JonasH The code is not production one. the goal is to understand how c# works. My question is: how is it possible that local x is captured by reference, as you can infer by the value of x after calling the lambda, and altough permit to call the lambda inside fun2, where x is out of scope

Answer (score 2):

This code uses 'a' lambda to increment 'a' variable:

- In fun1(), the variable 'x' has 'a' value of 3
- A lambda 'a' captures 'x' by reference (it modifies the original 'x')
- The lambda 'a' is called, incrementing 'x' to 4
- In fun2(), 'a' is called again, making 'x' inside the lambda 5
- Finally, fun1() and fun2() are called in the Main() method

So, 'x' goes from 3 to 4 in fun1() and then from 4 to 5 in fun2()

In typical scoping rules, x is indeed out of scope in fun2() when it's called in Main(). However, due to the way lambdas capture variables, it retains access to x even outside of its original scope

I hope this helps.

Comment: Problem: when fun2 is called in Main, x should be out of scope. I think that's what is throwing OP off.

Comment: That's right, I'll take another look and try to edit the answer. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: @Fildor, my friend's reply: In typical scoping rules, x is indeed out of scope in fun2() when it's called in Main(). However, due to the way lambdas capture variables, it retains access to x even outside of its original scope

Comment: Exactly. That should be added to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation is storing a copy of `x`, NOT a reference to `x`. We can see this by disassembling the output to view the generated IL.

Here's the internal class that's generated to handle the closure over `x`:

```
 .class nested private sealed auto ansi beforefieldinit
    '<>c__DisplayClass1_0'
      extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
  {
    .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor()
      = (01 00 00 00 )

    .field public int32 x

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void
      .ctor() cil managed
    {
      .maxstack 8

      IL_0000: ldarg.0      // this
      IL_0001: call         instance void [System.Runtime]System.Object::.ctor()
      IL_0006: nop
      IL_0007: ret

    } // end of method '<>c__DisplayClass1_0'::.ctor

    .method assembly hidebysig instance void
      '<fun1>b__0'() cil managed
    {
      .maxstack 2
      .locals init (
        [0] int32 V_0
      )

      // [20 19 - 20 20]
      IL_0000: nop

      // [20 21 - 20 25]
      IL_0001: ldarg.0      // this
      IL_0002: ldfld        int32 Console1.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1_0'::x
      IL_0007: ldc.i4.1
      IL_0008: add
      IL_0009: stloc.0      // V_0
      IL_000a: ldarg.0      // this
      IL_000b: ldloc.0      // V_0
      IL_000c: stfld        int32 Console1.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1_0'::x

      // [20 26 - 20 27]
      IL_0011: ret

    } // end of method '<>c__DisplayClass1_0'::'<fun1>b__0'
  } // end of class '<>c__DisplayClass1_0'
```

The important thing to notice here is the `.field public int32 x` member of the generated class, which is being used to store the value of `x`.

Also note the implementation of the lambda itself, the `'<fun1>b__0'()` method.

If you inspect the IL you'll see that it loads the `x` field using `ldfld int32 Console1.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1_0'::x` and then adds 1 to it and stores the result back into `Console1.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1_0'::x`.

Finally, the IL for the start of `fun1()` looks a bit like this:

```
 .method private hidebysig static void
    fun1() cil managed
  {
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
      [0] class Console1.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1_0' 'CS$<>8__locals0',
      [1] int32 b
    )

    IL_0000: newobj       instance void Console1.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1_0'::.ctor()
    IL_0005: stloc.0      // 'CS$<>8__locals0'

    // [15 5 - 15 6]
    IL_0006: nop

    // [17 9 - 17 19]
    IL_0007: ldloc.0      // 'CS$<>8__locals0'
    IL_0008: ldc.i4.3
    IL_0009: stfld        int32 Console1.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1_0'::x
```

At the start of that you can see it creating the `Action` wrapper class:

```
    IL_0000: newobj       instance void Console1.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1_0'::.ctor()
    IL_0005: stloc.0      // 'CS$<>8__locals0'
```

And then it loads that object and sets the `x` field to `3`:

```
    IL_0007: ldloc.0      // 'CS$<>8__locals0'
    IL_0008: ldc.i4.3
    IL_0009: stfld        int32 Console1.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass1_0'::x
```

That's where the `x` variable is being captured.

For more information, [see this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions) and [this article on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15624/Inside-C-2-0-Anonymous-Methods)